# Find route_table_id by subnet_id using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to figure out how to find route_table_id based upon a subnet_id(in a vpc) using boto3. There is api in boto3(v1.3.1), ec2.RouteTableAssociation(id). With correct route_table_association_id, try to access the resource's attribute route_table_id, it gives exception as below:

```
In [19]: rta.route_table_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceLoadException                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-a7f51e66ef03> in <module>()
----> 1 rta.route_table_id

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.pyc in property_loader(self)
    341                 else:
    342                     raise ResourceLoadException(
--> 343                         '{0} has no load method'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
    344
    345             return self.meta.data.get(name)

ResourceLoadException: ec2.RouteTableAssociation has no load method
```

I'm looking for a clue why this failed.

James

Comment: I am curious how the code looks like.

Answer (score 8):

figure out to do this way:

```
response = client.describe_route_tables(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'association.subnet-id',
            'Values': [
                source_subnet_id
            ]
        }
    ]
)


print(response['RouteTables'][0]['Associations'][0]['RouteTableId'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [describe_route_tables](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_route_tables).

All required info is under the responding JSON ['RouteTables'][*]["Associations"]